# Null coalescing operator (??) with return

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, null-coalescing

I was wondering why it is possible to do this in C# 7.0:

```
int? test = 0;
int test2 = test ?? throw new Exception("Error");
```

..but not this:

```
int? test = 0;
int test2 = test ?? return;
```

Can someone explain that?

Comment: I don't think the first one would compile.

Comment: It does test it yourself

Comment: Because `throw` is now an expression, and `return` is not (statement). https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression.md

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't compile in C# 6.0. I haven't yet experienced much with C# 7.0.

Comment: Other than that, I think this is applicable as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`throw` has relatively recently (in C# 7.0) been turned into an expression to enable this. `return` hasn't - it is a full statement. The `??` operator requires an expression, not a statement. It was an arbitrary choice by the C# designers, specifically to allow using `throw` with `??`.

[See the documentation on the `throw` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression)

Comment: Thanks alot, it is kinda sad since it would save some code!

Answer (score 1):

Well, because no one has implemented it this way. Or, more precisely, because `return` is not an expression.

`throw` used to be a statement only prior to C# 7.0, but then was extended (due to a proposal) to be an expression as well (only expressions are supported in the null coalescing operator).

So unless no one suggests to make `return` an expression, it won't work.

Comment: Where can you make suggestions then?

Comment: On the github page of the c# compiler

Comment: @Twenty exactly